# MySQL DATE_FORMAT vs SparkSQL date_format

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark

I have sql statment which i need to run in SparkSQl howewer I cannot properly date format it in spark
Mysql

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
```

SparkSQL

```
spark.sql("""
  SELECT date_format(current_date(),'yyyy-MM-01')"""
).show()
```

so what I am trying to achive , is take any date and convert in into first  day of the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used this , but I am shure thre is better solution,if you have it  feel free to share

```
spark.sql("""
  SELECT date_add( last_day( add_months(CAST(current_timestamp() as DATE), -1 ) ),1)
  """
).show()
```